# Singular form of the verb when there are other verbs with ing

Tags: verbs, grammatical-number

When you are writing a sentence like "embracing the variety of human beings brings you happiness", why do you have to write the verb in a singular form?

Comment: Related question, Singular vs. Plural with Multiple Gerunds as Subject (IE: [Gerund] and [Gerund] are/is [something].)(http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/116240/singular-vs-plural-with-multiple-gerunds-as-subject-ie-gerund-and-gerund).

Comment: Other verbs?  Do you mean "embracing"?  That's a verb form (a gerund, actually) acting as the subject of the sentence.  Is it singular or plural?  Do you mean "beings"?  That's an object of the preposition "of" and doesn't govern the verb.

Comment: Related question, [Singular or plural](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/104233/singular-or-plural). I think it is the closest duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

The default grammatical number for Subjects is singular. In order to deviate from this, the Subject must be considered plural in some way. "embracing the variety of human beings" does not have any kind of plural meaning, and so we see singular agreement in the verb form.