# Is it "are" or "is" when the noun is plural after a gerund?

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement

> Playing shooting games are/is my forte.
>
> Watching movies is/are fun.
>
> Reading books is or are good for you.

Do we use *is* or *are* for these sentences?

Comment: "is."  My forte **is** playing shooting games. Watching movies **is** fun. Reading books **is** good for you.

Comment: Thanks, that is a great technique. One more question, shooting games are my forte or fortes?

Comment: You're quite welcome! @rag "Shooting games are my forte."

Comment: Also see [Singular form of the verb when there are other verbs with ing](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/302588)

Comment: "Is". Gerunds are verbs.  Verbs can't be plural, so gerunds can't be plural.

Answer (score 1):

Is.  An easy way to determine this, in most cases, is to drop the nouns and evaluate the verbs.  Watching is...  Reading is...

Hope this helps.